# Python Logging not working - Logging object and sys.modules.pop()

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have a sitecustomize module in which I have instantiated a logger object. Currently I am required to load another sitecustomize.

Do I lose the logger object the moment I sys.modules.pop('sitecustomize')?
The reason I ask this is because all the logs after the modules.pop do not display or write anything.
If yes how can I continue logging? I tried instantiating it again after the pop, it didn't work.

Thanks for all the help and views in advance

```
logger = logging.getLogger('Blah')
logger.info('Attempting to current sitecustomize')
logger.debug('sys.modules %s', sys.modules)
if sys.modules.pop('sitecustomize',None) is not None:
    logger = logging.getLogger('Blah') # I tried this
    logger.info('Attempt Succeeded')
else:
    logger.info('Attempt Failed - see debug logs')

logger.info('Attempting to load next sitecustomize')

try:
    abc = imp.find_module('sitecustomize')
    xyz = imp.load_module('sitecustomize',*abc)
    sys.modules['sitecustomize'] = xyz
    logger.info('Attempt Succeeded')
except ImportError:
    logger.warning('Unable to find the new sitecustomize') # i know it may be silenced
except Exception as e:
    logger.info('Something else %', str(e))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apparently I just had to re import all the modules I previously imported (that are required after the pop).